# Bad chordal action in high gear

Tags: chain, derailleur-rear

On my smallest rear gear, the chain vibrates pretty noticeably causing it to "smack around" my front derailleur. It also produces a slight clicking noise from the rear of the bike.

I've adjusted the low and high limits on both derailleurs, and I can't seem to get rid of the noise. The only thing I can think of is to bend the front derailleur wider to prevent the chain from smacking it.

Comment: Do you mean the chain is rubbing the cage of the front derailleur? As in, it's just rubbing as you pedal? This is normal for small rear cog + small front chainring, and you should avoid this combination.

Comment: Adding to @WeiwenNg’s comment: the small chainring small cog combination creates large angulation in the chainline, which accelerates wear, increases friction, and just does not smoothly pass the chain. Hence, you should avoid that combination.

Comment: please add some photos from the RHS (right hand side, the side of the bike the chain is on) of the bike showing clearly the front mech.  I suspect its just out of position a little.

Comment: Do you have sufficient chain tension? With these kinds of problems it’s always a good idea to put the bike in a bike stand (or hang it up with a string from the saddle) and take a really close look at the drivetrain under slow pedaling. Does the chain mesh properly with the sprocket? Is it properly aligned? Is the rear derailleur bent? Is it rubbing against the front derailleur? These kinds of things.

Comment: @WeiwenNg It isn't exactly rubbing. The noise pattern is irregular, but frequent. When I would mount it to take a look, and run the pedals, I can see the chain vibrating back and forth, occasionally smacking the cage of the front derailleur.

Comment: @TedHohl it is the small chainring/small cog combo where this problem is noticeable. I've never seen a bike with this much vibration though. Will definitely keep it in mind though.

Comment: @Criggie what is RHS?

Comment: @Michael I'll check the rear derailleur for a tensioner of some kind today. Otherwise I've already ruled out most of those issues. I don't see any noticeable issues with meshing. Alignment looks good. No bends on derailleurs.

Comment: RHS = right hand side (drivetrain side).

Comment: Does it vibrate the same or differently when on the large chainring vs. the smallest chainring?  What rear derailleur are you using (there is reason for this question from my experience)? How old, or more importantly, how many miles/kms are on your current chain.  How many miles on your chainrings and your cassette?  What chainring and cassette gearing (and make/model?) are you using?

Comment: I would suspect that the chain is too loose.  (This would be due to too many links in the chain or a chain that's too worn.)

Comment: @DaMaxContent RHS is Right Hang Side, the side the chain is on..

Comment: “it is the small chainring/small cog combo where this problem is noticeable” – why are you using that combination? This is called _cross-chaining_, and though modern bikes generally cope with it ok-ish, it's still inadvisable, for multiple reasons. Does the problem also occur on big-chainring/small-sprocket?

Comment: @leftaroundabout didn't know about it. First bike that I've had noticed it on.

Answer (score 2):

Something I would look into. Chain tension (or how old the chain is) and chain lubrication/cleanliness. To me, it sounds like there is an offset caused by an old or dirty chain.

Comment: I'll take a look and see if I can find a tensioner on the rear derailleur today, and come back to you to see if this fixes the issue

Comment: Chain tension doesn't really have any influence on the front derailleur whilst staying in the same gear, because on the upper side the tension is dominated by pedalling force. (It can have an influence on how the front derailleur _shifts_, because that involves a change in used chain length, but this is not relevant otherwise.) If chain tension was the problem, you'd probably be having other problems (chain skipping on the rear sprockets or chain getting sucked up the front sprockets and jamming there).

Comment: There isn't a tensioner for the rear derailleur other than the b screw, and my derailleur hardly engages it. If you mention [leftaroundabout's comment](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/86393/bad-chordal-action-in-high-gear?noredirect=1#comment204043_86393), I'll mark it as the answer. Just "@" me when you've added it

Comment: Here's a [link to a highlight in an article](https://www.bicycling.com/training/a20047102/6-gearing-mistakes-youre-probably-making/#:~:text=Cross%2Dchaining%20is%20when%20you%E2%80%99re%20in%20your%20big%20chainring%20and%20the%20biggest%20cog%20on%20your%20back%20cassette%2C%20or%20on%20your%20small%20chainring%20and%20your%20smallest%20cog.%20The%20problem%20is%20that%20this%20stretches%20your%20chain%20diagonally%20to%20its%20limits%2C%20and%20needlessly%20so) you can use:

Comment: @leftaroundabout true and there could be two separate issues here, merged as one. An offset can be caused by a few things, clicking means chain tension, sprocket alignment, dirt/wear, or rear derailleur. While grinding, especially in the front, is alignment. 
If all else fails, see your local bike shop.